# Python 2.7.8: printing color/value with out the format

Tags: python, colors

I'm new to python and about a month into learning. I came across an issue where when I run this code it's supposed to print out the numbers in red. The second example shows what it really prints out and I'm stuck. Please help.

It's supposed to print `('Enemy HP:', 1150/1200)`
but it actually prints `('Enemy HP:', '\x1b[91m1150/1200\x1b[0m\n')`

```
import random

class bcolors:
    HEADER = '\033[95m'
    OKBLUE = "\x1b[94m"
    OKGREEN = "\x1b[92m"
    WARNING = '\033[93m'
    FAIL = '\x1b[91m'
    ENDC = '\033[0m'
    BOLD = '\033[1m'
    UNDERLINE = '\033[4m'


class Person:
    def __init__(self, hp, mp, atk, df, magic):
        self.maxhp = hp
        self.hp = hp
        self.maxmp = mp
        self.mp = mp
        self.atkl = atk - 10
        self.atkh = atk + 10
        self.df = df
        self.magic = magic
        self.actions = ["Attack", "Magic"]

    def generate_damage(self):
        return random.randrange(self.atkl, self.atkh)

    def generate_spell_damage(self, i):
        mgl = self.magic[i]["dmg"] - 5
        mgh = self.magic[i]["dmg"] + 5
        return random.randrange(mgl, mgh)

    def take_damage(self, dmg):
        self.hp -= dmg
        if self.hp < 0:
            self.hp = 0
        return self.hp

    def get_hp(self):
        return self.hp

    def get_max_hp(self):
        return self.maxhp

    def get_mp(self):
        return self.mp

    def get_max_mp(self):
        return self.maxmp

    def reduce_mp(self, cost):
        self.mp -= cost

    def get_spell_name(self, i):
        return self.magic[i]["name"]

    def get_spell_mp_cost(self, i):
        return self.magic[i]["cost"]

    def choose_action(self):
        i = 1
        print(bcolors.OKBLUE + bcolors.BOLD + "Actions" + bcolors.ENDC)
        for item in self.actions:
            print(str(i) + ":", item)
            i += 1

    def choose_magic(self):
        i = 1
        print(bcolors.OKBLUE + bcolors.BOLD + "Magic" + bcolors.ENDC)
        for spell in self.magic:
            print(str(i) + ":", spell["name"], "(cost:", str(spell["cost"]) + ")")
            i = 1



from classes.game import Person, bcolors


magic = [{"name": "Fire", "cost": 10, "dmg": 100},
         {"name": "Thunder", "cost": 10, "dmg": 124},
         {"name": "Blizzard", "cost": 10, "dmg": 100}]


player = Person(460, 65, 60, 34, magic)
enemy = Person(1200, 65, 45, 25, magic)

running = True
i = 0

print(bcolors.FAIL + bcolors.BOLD + "AN ENEMY ATTACKS!" + bcolors.ENDC)

while running:
    print("======================")
    player.choose_action()
    choice = input("Choose action:")
    index = int(choice) - 1

    if index == 0:
        dmg = player.generate_damage()
        enemy.take_damage(dmg)
        print("You attacked for", dmg, "points of damage.")
    elif index == 1:
        player.choose_magic()
        magic_choice = int(input("Choose magic:")) - 1
        magic_dmg = player.generate_spell_damage(magic_choice)
        spell = player.get_spell_name(magic_choice)
        cost = player.get_spell_mp_cost(magic_choice)

        current_mp = player.get_mp()

        if cost > current_mp:
            print(bcolors.FAIL + "\nNot enough MP\n" + bcolors.ENDC)
            continue

        player.reduce_mp(cost)
        enemy.take_damage(magic_dmg)
        print(bcolors.OKBLUE + "\n" + spell + " deals", str(magic_dmg), "points of damage" + bcolors.ENDC)


    enemy_choice = 1

    enemy_dmg = enemy.generate_damage()
    player.take_damage(enemy_dmg)
    print("Enemy attacks for", enemy_dmg)

    print("----------------------------")
    print("Enemy HP:", bcolors.FAIL + str(enemy.get_hp()) + "/" + str(enemy.get_max_hp()) + bcolors.ENDC + "\n")

    print("Your HP:", bcolors.OKGREEN + str(player.get_hp()) + "/" + str(player.get_max_hp()) + bcolors.ENDC)
    print("Your MP:", bcolors.OKBLUE + str(player.get_mp()) + "/" + str(player.get_max_mp()) + bcolors.ENDC + "\n")



    if enemy.get_hp() == 0:
        print(bcolors.OKGREEN + "You Win!", + bcolors.ENDC)
        running = False
    elif player.get_hp() == 0:
        print(bcolors.FAIL + "Your enemy has defeated you!" + bcolors.ENDC)
        running = False
```

Comment: What console/terminal are you using? ANSI color flags aren't supported on every platform, for example the windows command prompt.

Comment: Hey Kevin, im using pycharm on windows 10 machine.

Comment: i had this working before but my hard drive failed and i lost everything, lesson learned don't save to local.

Comment: I won't post this as an answer since it's a resource recommendation, but the third party module [colorama](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/colorama) can make ANSI escape sequences work on Windows.

Answer (score 1):

Your code would work well in Python 3, where `print` is a function:

```
>>> print("x", "y")
x y
```

It means "print the first argument, then the separator (which defaults to a space), then the second argument.

In Python 2, though:

```
>>> print("x", "y")
('x', 'y')
```

prints a representation of the tuple containing your strings.

So, you can either use Python 3, which has many advantages, or change your code like this:

```
print("Enemy HP:" + bcolors.FAIL + str(enemy.get_hp()) + "/" +  
      str(enemy.get_max_hp()) + bcolors.ENDC + "\n")
# note the + instead of ,
```

in order to print a single string.

Comment: YAAAA!  when i changed my code to remove the print("Enemy HP:", and replaced it with print("Enemy HP:" + it worked. I think i'm gonna update to python 3. Thanks all for your help, Python is sure fun...when it works.

Answer (score -1):

does it work for your others print ?

You have a double quote "" instead off simple '' on OKGREEN in class bcolors maybe it comes from here

Comment: No, there's no difference between single quote and double quote in Python.

Comment: yes, things like print(bcolors.FAIL + bcolors.BOLD + "AN ENEMY ATTACKS!" + bcolors.ENDC) work fine. the lines that have print enemy hp and your hp your mp it puts the extra character before and after. here is what it prints: Actions
('1:', 'Attacks')
('2:', 'Magic')
Choose action:1
('You attacked for', 50, 'points of damage.')
('Enemy attacks for', 40)
----------------------------
('Enemy HP:', '\x1b[91m1150/1200\x1b[0m\n')
('Your HP:', '\x1b[92m420/460\x1b[0m')
('Your MP:', '\x1b[94m65/65\x1b[0m\n')

Comment: no,the double "" was me playing around to see if it made a difference.